Two approaches to counting ways are giving different answers
It is given that out of 10 computers, 4 are functional and the rest are not and it is asked "What is the probability of choosing 4 computers and getting at least 3 functional ones". I tried 2 approaches:

$$P(\text{at least 3 functional}) =\frac{\binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$ Here we are choosing 3 of the 4 functional ones and then 1 from the remaining 7 (there's 6 non-functional and 1 functional computers remaining)

$$P(\text{at least 3 functional}) =\frac{1}{\binom{10}{4}} + \frac{\binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$ Here we are considering the 2 possibilities of choosing all functional and 3 functional + 1 non-functional separately.


To me both methods seemed correct but only the second one is giving the correct answer. Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with the first method?

Curios, you should learn to use MathJax in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

First method overcounts. For instance: You count choosing 4 functioning computers four times, once each for which of the four is the "additional" one after choosing the other three.

Edited using the reference @Angelo

Curios, you should also read this thread in order to learn how to ask a good question on this site.

@ArturoMagidin, I see what you are saying. Is my understanding correct that where I went wrong in the first approach is that I considered the 2 sets as separate in the first part (choosing 3 from only the 4) but then combined the 2 sets in the second part (now choosing 1 from a combined set with 7 remaining); leading to the overcount since the working ones are now present in both sets but the sets should have been mutually exclusive?

As has been mentioned by Arturo Magidin in comments, in the first formula, you are over counting, as you don't know which $3$ are in the first part
The $2nd$ formula is corect and  can more explicitly be written as
$$P(\text{At Least 3 functional}) = \frac{\binom44\binom60+\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$
